# Typeclass behavior in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As a beginner to Haskell I'm having a hard time understanding why this is failing

```
-- this works fine of course
f :: Float
f = 1.0

f :: Num a => a
f = 1.0
-- Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
--      from the context: Num a
--        bound by the type signature for:
--                   f :: forall a. Num a => a
```

My confusion stems from them both having instances of Num. So since Int's, Integers, Doubles, etc all have an instance of the Num typeclass, why can't I stuff any numerical value in `f`?

For example, `negate` which has a signature
`negate :: Num a => a -> a` will work with Int's Float's Doubles, etc.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Literals are syntactic sugar in the following sense: 10 is converted to `fromInteger (10 :: Integer)` and 10.5 is converted to `fromRational ((21 :% 2) :: Rational)`. Look at what the types of `fromInteger` and `fromRational` are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why can't I stuff any numerical value in `f`?
>
> For example, negate which has a signature `negate :: Num a => a -> a` will work with `Int`'s `Float`'s `Double`s, etc.

Precisely because of that!

You can't stuff any numerical value in the *definition* of `f`, as you can't stuff any numerical value in the *definition* of `negate`.

Suppose we tried to define `negate` as follows

```
negate :: Num a => a -> a
negate x = 10.5 - 10.5 - x
```

Would that work on an `Int`? That is, on `negate 42 :: Int`? No, since `10.5` is not an `Int`.

Since the type of `negate` promises that it works on any numeric type, including `Int`, but it does not actually work on `Int`, then the promise is broken. Static type checking rejects that code because of this.

Similarly, if type checking accepted

```
f :: Num a => a
f = 10.5
```

then all of these should work: `f + 8 :: Int`, `f / 2 :: Double`, `f - 4 :: Integer`.
But `10.5` does not fit into `Int` (nor into `Integer`).

The issue here is that `f :: Num a => a` allows the *caller* to choose any numeric type `a`. Since the type allows the caller to choose, `f` can not choose itself, but must adapt to any choice made by the caller. So, `f` can not use code which only works at some numeric types, but not others.

If `f` only works at `Fractional` types, a subset of `Num` types, then the type of `f` must advertise to the caller that its choice is limited to fractional types. This is done by using `f :: Fractional a => a` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that when you write `f :: Num a => a`, this means that `f` must work for *all* possible instantiations of `a` such that a `Num a` instance exists. In particular, this means that writing `(f :: Int)` somewhere else should work fine, since `instance Num Int` certainly exists. However, the value that you wrote for `f` to return is `1.0`, which is not an integer: `1.0 :: Fractional p => p`. The error message is basically saying that "Knowing that `a` is a `Num` doesn't tell us that `a` is a `Fractional`, so there's no way for the fractional literal  1.0 to have type `a`".

One way to think about it is that the *caller* gets to choose what `a` should be: this is why type signatures of this form are called *universally quantified*.

You may be thinking of *existential* quantification: `f` returns some kind of `Num`, but the "caller" doesn't know what `Num` was returned.  This is often not as useful as universal quantification, and is a little clunky in Haskell, but can be done like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-} -- This is a GHC extension
-- A SomeNum value contains some kind of Num. Can't see what kind from the "outside".
data SomeNum = forall a. Num a => SomeNum a
f :: SomeNum
f = SomeNum 5.0
```

In Haskell, a signature like `f :: a` is syntax for the (conceptually clearer) `f :: forall a. a`, where the `forall` is a lot like a "type-level lambda" (and not the `f :: exists a. a` which you may have been thinking of). In fact, if you look at GHC Core, you will see that all these type applications are explicit: whenever you use a universally quantified function, the "caller" explicitly passes in the types to use for each of the type variables.

However, I would advise that you not try to use existential quantification at this stage: there are often better/easier alternatives. I just wanted to explain it to help show the difference between existentials and universals.

Comment: I think I understand. So by saying something has `Num a => a`, it has to take a fairly polymorphic type, like `1` which could be an `Int`, could be an `Integer`. But by giving it the value `1.0`, that's obviously a concrete type, a `Fractional` and that violates the agreement of the type signature `Num a => a` which is saying 'whatever type you give me can't be more specific than a `Num a => a` type; if it's more specific you need to define a more specific type'

Comment: Yes, basically! The `Num a => a` signature is saying that the definition has to work for any `Num a`, but you only defined how it works for a `Fractional a`. This particular example is slightly more complicated since `Fractional` is also a type class, but since there are some `Num` instances which aren't `Fractional` instances, it still violates the agreement with the "outside" that `f` should work for any `a` such that `Num a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply write

```
f = 10.5
```

you get back `f :: Fractional a => a` without a problem.

It is when you explicitly claim its type to be `Num a => a`, Haskell must unify the proclaimed and the actual types, and it can't, since `Fractional` is `Num`'s ***subclass***:

```
>> :i Fractional
class Num a => Fractional a where
  --  ^^^                              -- Fractional is Num's subclass
  ...........
  fromRational :: Rational -> a
  ...........
```

**Every `Fractional` is a `Num`, but not every `Num` is a `Fractional`.**

---

The type of `fromRational` is `fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a`.

This  suggests that floating point literals like `10.5` are actually read as `fromRational (10.5 :: Rational)`, just like whole number literals like `10` are read as `fromInteger (10 :: Integer)`.

Indeed, section 10.3 in the [Haskell tutorial](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) reads:

> An integer numeral (without a decimal point) is actually equivalent to an application of `fromInteger` to the value of the numeral as an `Integer`. Similarly, a floating numeral (with a decimal point) is regarded as an application of `fromRational` to the value of the numeral as a `Rational`. Thus, `7` has the type `(Num a) => a`, and `7.3` has the type `(Fractional a) => a`.

Answer (score 0):

When you give the compiler a type declaration like `f :: Num a => a`, you're not just saying `f` has the typeclass `Num` but that that's *all* you know about it here. Since you've entered `1.0`, not `1`, the compiler concludes that you also need `Fractional`. Your declaration said that you don't, and so this can't compile. It does compile if you say it's `Fractional a => a`, and [`Fractional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) implies `Num`.

Comment: As a beginner of Haskell as well, makes me wonder: isn't the result of `f` covariant, like in C-like languages (returning `1.0` from a function/method that has an `object` return type)?

Comment: C will insert type conversions pretty much anywhere based on type coercion; it's not a property of the function, only something the compiler can do with the value that was returned. Haskell doesn't do implicit type conversions; if you want to add a `Float` and a `Double`, you have to convert one or the other, for instance through [`realToFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac).

Comment: @Caramiriel There's no subtyping, so the question of covariance doesn't arise.